# MongoDB get docs where month of date is equal to specific month

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

i have collection `vacation` that looks like something like this :

```
[
  {
  _id: ..
  employeeId: ...
  type: ...
  startDate:2022-09-10T00:00:00.000+00:00
  endDate: 2022-09-15T00:00:00.000+00:00
  }
  {
  _id: ..
  employeeId: ...
  type: ...
  startDate:2022-01-10T00:00:00.000+00:00
  endDate: 2022-02-15T00:00:00.000+00:00
  }
  {
  _id: ..
  employeeId: ...
  type: ...
  startDate:2022-03-10T00:00:00.000+00:00
  endDate: 2022-04-15T00:00:00.000+00:00
  }
]
...
```

i want to get docs only when the month in `startDate` is equal to specific month

```
const Vacation = require("../models/Vacation");

const vacations = await Vacation.find({// where month in startDate is equal to 2})
```

how can i perform such query ? thanks in advance

Comment: Are the values stored as **string** or as `Date` objects?

Comment: as ```Date``` objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an aggregation query like this:

```
const vacations = await Vacation.aggregate(
 [
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$month": {
              "$dateFromString": {
                "dateString": "$startDate",
              }
            }
          },
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
 ]
);
```

Here we, construct a date object from a string using `$dateFromString` operator, and then find the month value using `$month`. Then we perform an equality comparison, using `$eq`. Read more about aggregation operations on MongoDB [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/). See the above query working [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/maRG_RX_bd6).

Comment: In case the values are properly stored as `Date` values, simply use `$eq: [{$month: "$startDate"},3]`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you don't need `$dateFromString` when date values are stored correctly:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$eq": [{ "$month": "$startDate" }, 3 ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```